# Как работать с Callback?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

[image: screen]Как только начал я осваивать dart/flutter возникла одна проблема. Как можно передать данные из одного метода в другой? Как я понял, я пытаюсь вынести переменную из асинхронной ф-ии. И проблема в том, что значение переменной за пределы скобок равна нулю. Знаю с помощью callback функции можно передать данные в другой метод, но совсем не понимаю как работают callback в dart.

```
  Future<Book> getBooks() async {
    Book book = new Book();
    FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("posts")
        .onValue
        .listen((Event event) {
      Map<String, dynamic> myMap =
          new Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);
      myMap.forEach((key, value) {
        book.title = value["user"];
        onGetTitle();
      }); // здесь переменная имеет значении 
      return book;
    });
     // а вот здесь равна нулю.
    return book;
  }
```

Comment: `onValue` это `stream`, `listen` это `StreamSubscription`, в `listen` `onData` это обработчик а не callback. Если вы не умеете в `stream`, то вам только так работать:  `var books = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("posts").onValue.firstWhere((e) {...});`

Comment: Тогда получается я не смогу его слушать? Не буду знать изменились ли данные в базе или нет без listen? В java я мог например вытащить значение так и использовать в другом месте:        ```interface onCallback {
  onGetBook(String book);
}
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
.child("posts")
.onValue
    .listen((Event event) {
      book = event.snapshot.value;
      onGetBook(book);
}
``` Есть ли такой способ здесь? И объясните пожалуйста, почему за пределы скобок book равен null?

Comment: Если вам нужно в реал тайме работать с данными, то работаете через `stream`. Через `StreamTransformer` можно преобразовывать поток в нужный тип. Ответ на ваши вопросы: нет нельзя. Потому-что это по сути асинхронный итератор, он не может вычислит значение типа, пока тот не закончит. По этому есть возможность получить значение по выборки, либо работать через `stream api`

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться.